# PHP Function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this function that I use in Laravel, its purpose is to parse the contents of a controller folder and get the Controller names and their actions/functions.

Works ok but when I add a subfolder with Controller files in it, then it doesn't look in them

```
function getControllerActions($path, $namespace)
{
    $path = app_path() . $path;
    $controllers = [];

    foreach (new \DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
        if ($fileInfo->isDir()) {
            continue;
        }

        if (file_exists($path . $fileInfo->getFilename())) {
            $controller = str_replace('.php', '', $fileInfo->getFilename());
            $className = $namespace . $controller;
            $class = new \ReflectionClass($className);

            $methodNames = [];
            $lowerClassName = strtolower($className);
            foreach ($class->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method) {
                if (strtolower($method->class) == $lowerClassName) {
                    $methodNames[] = $method->name;
                }
            }
            $controllers[str_replace('Controller', '', $controller)] = $methodNames;
        }
    }
    return $controllers;
}
```

And as I said it works correctly.

I need to organize my controllers, so I need to add them to subfolders.  I edited accordingly but cant get it to work.

```
function getControllerActions($path, $namespace)
{
    $path = app_path() . $path;
    $controllers = [];
    $subnamespace = [];
    $subpath = [];

    foreach (new \DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
        if ($fileInfo->isDir()) {
            $subpath = $path . $fileInfo . '/';
            $subnamespace = $namespace . $fileInfo;
            foreach (new \DirectoryIterator($subpath) as $SubfileInfo) {
                    if (file_exists($subpath . $SubfileInfo->getFilename())) {
                    $controller = str_replace('.php', '', $SubfileInfo->getFilename());
                    $className = $subnamespace . '\\' . $controller;
                    $class = new \ReflectionClass($className);

                    $methodNames = [];
                    $lowerClassName = strtolower($className);
                    foreach ($class->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method) {
                        if (strtolower($method->class) == $lowerClassName) {
                            $methodNames[] = $method->name;
                        }
                    }
                    $controllers[str_replace('Controller', '', $controller)] = $methodNames;
                }
            }
        }

        if (file_exists($path . $fileInfo->getFilename())) {
            $controller = str_replace('.php', '', $fileInfo->getFilename());
            $className = $namespace . $controller;
            $class = new \ReflectionClass($className);

            $methodNames = [];
            $lowerClassName = strtolower($className);
            foreach ($class->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method) {
                if (strtolower($method->class) == $lowerClassName) {
                    $methodNames[] = $method->name;
                }
            }
            $controllers[str_replace('Controller', '', $controller)] = $methodNames;
        }
    }
    return $controllers;
}
```

I get an error

> (1/1) ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\admin\core..
> does not exist

This is the correct namespace ,but it should add the controller name where the .. are.

The funny thing is when I change the

```
$className = $subnamespace . '-' . $controller;
```

I get the error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\admin\core-TransationsController

Which shows the first controller in the core sub-directory

Any Ideas.....

Comment: can you add the example `namespace` from the controller, which placed in the subfolder?

Comment: The controler TransationsController has :

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin\core;